# Why, not How: Stata incorrectly identifies var type on large dataset with mixed (string+numeric) values within vars

Tags: stata

I'm reading in a 5 million observation pipe delimited text file. One column's first 250,000 values are numeric; the remainder are string. The code below has imported the first 250,000 numeric values, declared the variable to be numeric (long), and treated the string values as missing.

`import delimited "mixed_types.txt", delimiter("|")`

Solution: import all vars as strings and then destring:

```
import delimited "mixed_types.txt", delimiter("|") stringcols(_all)
destring, replace
```

My question is, why? The help file for import delimited states, “import delimited will check if the file is delimited by tabs or commas **based on the first line of data.**" Is this rule followed for ascribing var types?

Comment: Is your Stata installation up to date? The problem you present seems inconsistent with Example 3 of the manual entry for `import delimited`. I can't test for the moment,  but make sure your problem is reproducible posting a minimal example (that includes data).

Comment: The problem occurs on the Unix version of Stata 14 -- which we've last updated on April 2. The link below indicates the problem was patched on June 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not expected behavior.

From http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?whatsnew read:

> 10. import delimited has the following fixes:
>
>     a.  import delimited, when string data were not present until row
>                number 5,000 or higher for a variable in the imported text file,
>                incorrectly chose a numeric data type instead of a string data
>                type for that variable.  This has been fixed.

You need to `update`. See `help update`.

(The same information can be accessed running `help whatsnew`. The update is for Stata 14.)